# How to use async.js libary with an await?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, async.js

I'm trying to implement the `async` library so that it polls an API for a transaction until one of them succeeds.

```
router.get('/', async function (req, res) {
      let apiMethod = await service.getTransactionResult(txHash).execute();

      async.retry({times: 60, interval: 1000}, apiMethod, function(err, result) {
           if(err){
              console.log(err);
           }else{
              return result;
           }
           
      });
});

module.exports = router;
```

How ever I can't figure out the correct syntax with the `apiMethod`'s `await` function.

I'm getting the error `Error: Error: Invalid arguments for async.retry`

How do I implement it so the errors are all logged everytime it fails and also how to successfully exit the 60 retry loop if it succeeds before all 60 are finished? (if it finishes at for example 14, stop the retries).

Comment: ...why? [Promise.race](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race) already exists?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [async-retry](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-retry) library.

```js
await retry(
  async (bail) => {
    const res = await service.getTransactionResult(txHash).execute();
    if (res.status >= 400) {
      bail(new Error());
      return;
    }

    const data = await res.text();
    return data;
  },
  {
    retries: 60,
  }
);
```

Comment: What's the difference between the two libraries? I honestly can't tell the difference after checking the github readme's and ```npm``` pages

Answer (score 0):

As I can see it, `apiMethod` is supposed to be an unresolved promise, try this out

```
router.get('/', async function (req, res) {
      let apiMethod = () => (service.getTransactionResult(txHash).execute())

      async.retry({times: 60, interval: 1000}, apiMethod, function(err, result) {
           if(err){
              console.log(err);
           }else{
              return result;
           }
           
      });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: the else statement never gets fired

Comment: what is the logged error?

Comment: the error is not fired either. Full code: https://pastebin.com/9tJqC2dK

Comment: try `let apiMethod = service.getTransactionResult(txHash).execute `

Comment: that just throws the same error in my question

Answer (score 0):

```
var promises = [];
    let request = service.getTransactionResult(txHash);
    for(let i = 0; i < 60; i++){
        promises.push(request);
    }
    for(let i = 0; i < 60; i++){
        try{
            let result = await promises[i].execute();
        }catch(err){
            console.log(err);
            await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
        }
        
    }
```

I couldn't figure out how to do it with the async library but this worked for polling in my situation where the error would be thrown and waits a second when the transaction hasn't been processed yet and then retried.